# Restrict published event to certain user groups in Plone

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I am using Plone 4.3.3 and am trying o do the following:

When admin adds new Event, I would like them to be able to specify user group which should be able to view that event in their calendar. Any user that does not belong to that user group is not supposed to see that event.

I see that only published events are viewable in the calendar, so the admin will have to publish it.
On the other hand, "Share" tab-> "Can view" only works for private events, once the event is published it is visible by any user.

What would be the way to restrict published events to a certain user group, so that users outside of that group would not see it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think published means what you think it means, or at least it has a certain prescribed notion of "published === public".  Why publish the item?  You likely want a custom workflow definition, see http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/workflow.html

Comment: I should add that you could have a workflow definition assigned to just event type (site-wide) or use placeful workflow policy support in Plone to just use this workflow definition in certain places on the site, but obviously you have to create a custom workflow definition (states and transitions/menu-actions) first.

Answer (score 0):

The portal_calendar tool, from ZMI, allow you add new states to events shown in calendar.
Obviously, calendar configuration apart, security matters and only events that the user can really see are shown.

So you can add "private" state here the you can play with the sharing.